# I want to make the first tab in this accordion to be opened by default -without jQuery or bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I want to make the first tab in this accordion to be opened by default without jQuery or boostrap.

Code:-

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Add the `.active` class to the button, and style the panel with `display: block;`.

```
<button class="accordion active">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel" style="display: block;">
```

---

**Full Working Code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion active">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel" style="display: block;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Brother for your answer I really appreciate it. Thank you very much.....